# How to override double or even 3 times clicking Power button or even Volume UP/DOWN keys in Android Using a service in the background?

Tags: java, android, service

I am developing an application where I could listen to **POWER_BUTTON** clicked for 3 times consecutively in 3-5 seconds.

I have searched all the StackOverflow for answers but none of them has worked for me.

This answer from [Lars D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android) which should work on the activity doesn't work too though it is accepted.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivitySetupMenu.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

There is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brink.powerbuttonflashlight&hl=en) that is intending to do this, I installed it but still, it doesn't work maybe the API they used are depreciated or even has been removed.

**The Reasons why these solutions do not work** :

1. when the App gets killed/destroyed and it no longer detects.
2. The screen is locked and again it no longer detects.
3. Maybe the SDK does not support it.

Maybe we can find a way to do it on the activity but I want to listen to the actions using a **service/broadcast Receiver** while the app is killed/in the background/when screen locked/ when screen off.

Well, this question is definitely repeated many times on StackOverflow but no complete or working answer has been given.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for your considerations, I wasn't focusing on the phrasing actually, but anyhow just waiting for anyone to answer.

Comment: You might have to wait much longer, not to say forever, with a less readable, less easily answerable question... Making a question which is clear, easy to read and easy to answer (with appropriate knowhow of course) is the key to getting fast and good help. Try the [edit] link while you are waiting anyway.

Comment: I have brought some edits, feel free if you wanted to edit it. @Yunnosch

Comment: Much better now. Now I have to admit that I cannot help you with this.

Comment: that is removed too

Comment: I noticed. :-) Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody tried to solve the question or maybe couldn't even understand the question, fortunately after many hours of searching the web I found this awesome [website](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-keep-broadcast-receiver-running-after-application-exit/) that solves exactly my problem and wanted to post it here too.

Problems which are solved now :

1. My Application always runs in the background even if it is killed/destroyed or removed from the System Tray.
2. The service always listens to the POWER_BUTTON when clicked.
3. The SDK supports this since it uses only BroadCast Receivers and Services.

I am just writing down the steps in case the link may not work or be removed in future:

**1.First we will create a broadcast receiver** which can listen and process android screen on / off broadcast event as below.

**ScreenOnOffReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ScreenOnOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final static String SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG = "SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action))
    {
        Log.d(SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, "Screen is turn off.");
    }else if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action))
    {
        Log.d(SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, "Screen is turn on.");
    }}
}
```

**2. Register And Unregister ScreenOnOffReceiver In Activity.**

Now we will create an activity and register ScreenOnOffReceiver in it’s onCreate() method, and unregister the receiver in it’s onDestroy() method as below.

**ScreenOnOffActivity.java**

```
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.dev2qa.example.R;
import com.dev2qa.example.broadcast.receiver.ScreenOnOffReceiver;

public class ScreenOnOffActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ScreenOnOffReceiver screenOnOffReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_on_off);

        setTitle("dev2qa.com - Keep BroadcastReceiver Running After App Exit.");

        // Create an IntentFilter instance.
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

        // Add network connectivity change action.
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");

        // Set broadcast receiver priority.
        intentFilter.setPriority(100);

        // Create a network change broadcast receiver.
        screenOnOffReceiver = new ScreenOnOffReceiver();

        // Register the broadcast receiver with the intent filter object.
        registerReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver, intentFilter);

        Log.d(ScreenOnOffReceiver.SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, "onCreate: screenOnOffReceiver is registered.");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Unregister screenOnOffReceiver when destroy.
        if(screenOnOffReceiver!=null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver);
            Log.d(ScreenOnOffReceiver.SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, "onDestroy: screenOnOffReceiver is unregistered.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Run Above Activity In Below Steps.**

1. Start the activity, there is a log message which said the broadcast receiver has been registered in the activity’s onCreate() method.
2. Press the power button to turn off screen.
3. Press the power button again to turn on screen.
4. You can see log data in android monitor console for above steps.
5. Type the back menu to exit the activity. You can see the broadcast receiver is unregistered in the activity’s onDestroy() method also.
6. Press the power button to execute step 2 , 3 again, but there is not any log data printed in the android monitor console.

[image: Runnindg Activity]

**3. Register And Unregister Broadcast Receiver** In Android Background Service

When you register the broadcast receiver in activity, it will be stopped after the activity exit.

To resolve this problem, we will create an android service object, and register and unregister the broadcast receiver in the service object.

Because the android service object will still run at the background after the activity exit, so the broadcast receiver will still run also after the android app exit.

**3.1 Create Android Service Class.**

**3.1.1 Create A Java Class That Extends android.app.Service.**

**ScreenOnOffBackgroundService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import ScreenOnOffReceiver;

public class ScreenOnOffBackgroundService extends Service {

    private ScreenOnOffReceiver screenOnOffReceiver = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Create an IntentFilter instance.
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

        // Add network connectivity change action.
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");

        // Set broadcast receiver priority.
        intentFilter.setPriority(100);

        // Create a network change broadcast receiver.
        screenOnOffReceiver = new ScreenOnOffReceiver();

        // Register the broadcast receiver with the intent filter object.
        registerReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver, intentFilter);

        Log.d(ScreenOnOffReceiver.SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, "Service onCreate: screenOnOffReceiver is registered.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Unregister screenOnOffReceiver when destroy.
        if(screenOnOffReceiver!=null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver);
            Log.d(ScreenOnOffReceiver.SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, "Service onDestroy: screenOnOffReceiver is unregistered.");
        }
    }
}
```

**3.1.2 Add Service Xml Tag In AndroidManifest.xml File.**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="put your own package">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
        <activity android:name=".broadcast.activity.ScreenOnOffActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".broadcast.service.ScreenOnOffBackgroundService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**3.1.3 Change Activity Java Code To Below.**

Please notice the java code that start the service object.

```
Intent backgroundService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenOnOffBackgroundService.class);
startService(backgroundService);
```

**ScreenOnOffActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.dev2qa.example.R;
import com.dev2qa.example.broadcast.receiver.ScreenOnOffReceiver;
import com.dev2qa.example.broadcast.service.ScreenOnOffBackgroundService;

public class ScreenOnOffActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ScreenOnOffReceiver screenOnOffReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_on_off);

        setTitle("dev2qa.com - Keep BroadcastReceiver Running After App Exit.");

        Intent backgroundService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenOnOffBackgroundService.class);
        startService(backgroundService);

        Log.d(ScreenOnOffReceiver.SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, "Activity onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(ScreenOnOffReceiver.SCREEN_TOGGLE_TAG, "Activity onDestroy");
    }
}
```

Run the example again, you can see below picture. From the logcat output, we can see the broadcast receiver still running after the android app exit.

[image: Android Keep Broadcast Receiver GIF]
<sub>(source: [dev2qa.com](https://www.dev2qa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/android-run-broadcast-receiver-in-background-service.gif))</sub>

Comment: Answering your own question after finding out a solution is very appreciated. However, it would be even better to summarise the actual solution instead of only linking. That does not mean copying large parts, just the basic steps. The idea is that the answer stays helpful (at least by putting future readers on the right track) even if the linked page dies.

Comment: I will put the steps though it would be copied.

Comment: @Yunnosch though I put the complete answer though it is so long, hoping this would help someone.

Comment: Did you read this part of my comment: "summarise the actual solution instead of only linking. That does not mean copying large parts"? A summary would be enough. There also is a trap in copying too much without attributing, but you avoided that one by keeping the link.

Comment: @Yunnosch I did read your part, the reason I did that was in case that website is down or the link may start not working or any other issues, the full answer still should exist.